# Trying to upload a file using asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am loading product images in from the partial shared view, I am trying to use Ifrom file which was suggested in the previous question.

So in my product controller, I have the following method

**Edit**

I only want to save the path of the file in the database and then save the file on the disk what is the correct way of achieving this.

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(ProductImages model)
{
   if (model.Image != null)
   {
      var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
      var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, GetUniqueName(model.Image.FileName));
            model.Image.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
    }
        // to do  : Return something
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

}
```

My Product Images class

```
public class ProductImages
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductImageId { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductImageTitle { get; set; }
    public string ProductImageUploadUrl { get; set; }
    public string ProductImageRealPath { get; set; }
    public string ServerIpAddress { get; set; }
    public string ProductImageAltTag { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { set; get; }
}
```

My Shared layout which I am Loading via following.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="images">
        Product Images
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ProductPicture", Model)
</div>
```

This is the code for my shared view I think I am doing something wrong with the way I have declared the IFormFile

```
@model solitude.models.ProductImages

   <div class="form-group">

    <form asp-action="FileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input asp-for="ImageCaption" />
        <input asp-for="ImageDescription" />
        <input asp-for="MyImage" />

        <input type="submit" />


        </form>


</div>
```

I am receiving the following error

> > AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The property 'ProductImages.Image' is of an interface type ('IFormFile'). If it is
> >     a navigation property manually configure the relationship for this
> >     property by casting it to a mapped entity type, otherwise ignore the
> >     property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using
> >     'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.)
> >     System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool
> >     includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>
> InvalidOperationException: The property 'ProductImages.Image' is of an
>   interface type ('IFormFile'). If it is a navigation property manually
>   configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped
>   entity type, otherwise ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]'
>   attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

**Edit 2**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(ProductImageVm model)
{
    if (model.Image != null)
    {
        var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
        var fileId = GetUniqueName(model.Image.FileName);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, fileId);
        model.Image.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));

    // to do  : Save the record in ProductImage table
    var pi = new ProductImages { ProductID = model.ProductId };
    pi.ProductImageTitle = model.Title;
    pi.ProductImageRealPath = fileId; //Storing the fileId
    _context.ProductImages.Add(pi);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

}
```

Now one thing I am loading the form within another form could this be the problem

Comment: To start with, You want to store the file in both disk and in the database  ? for database you should use byte array as property type in your entity. IFormFile should be used in your view model.

Comment: Hi @Shyju I only want to store the path of the file in the db and then the file on disk. Sorry should have been more clear.

Comment: @Shyju I re adjusted that on the edit there so I did to make it more clear to new people on this question.

Comment: So if you don’t want to store it in the database the error message explains what to do so it won’t attempt to save it. That should fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using `IFormFile` type property in your entity class. As per the comment, you want to store the image in the disk and store the path to the image in the table. So just remove the `public IFormFile Image { set; get; }` property from your entity class definition.

You can use `IFormFile` in your view model which is used to transfer data between your view and action method. So create a view model with properties needed from the view

```
public class ProductImageVm
{
   public int ProductId { set;get;}
   public string Title { set;get;}
   public IFormFile Image { set; get; }
   //Add other properties AS NEEDED by your view
}
```

Now to upload the image for product 56 ,create an object of this view model, set the ProductId to 56 and send to the view in your GET action. In the view, we will keep the productId in a hidden form field which can be used later in the HttpPost action when we need to save a new `ProductImages` entity record.

```
public IActionResult UploadImage(int productId)
{
  var vm = new ProductImageVm { ProductId=productId};
  return View(vm);
}
```

and the view,which is strongly typed to our view model

```
@model ProductImageVm    
<form asp-action="FileUpload" asp-controller="Products" method="post"
                                                        enctype="multipart/form-data">    
        <input asp-for="Title" />
        <input asp-for="ProductId" type="hidden" />
        <input asp-for="Image" />    
        <input type="submit" />       
</form>
```

Now in your HttpPost action method, you use the same view model as the parameter, read the `Image` property and save it to disk and store the path in your table. You do not need to store the full path. You can store the relative path. In the below sample, i am storing the unique file Id(the file name) to the `ProductImageRealPath` property value when saving a ProductImages entity record.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(ProductImageVm model)
{
   if (model.Image != null)
   {
      var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
      var fileId = GetUniqueName(model.Image.FileName);
      var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads,fileId);
      model.Image.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
    }
    // to do  : Save the record in ProductImage table
    var pi=new ProductImages { ProductId = model.ProductId};
    pi.ProductImageTitle = model.Title;
    pi.ProductImageRealPath = fileId; //Storing the fileId
    db.ProductImages.Add(pi);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

}
```

Comment: So that mean i need to create a class for my upload then just didnt make since but thank you

Comment: Yes. It is always good to separate your UI layer concerns with data access layers . The first step is not to use your data access layer entity classes in razor views. Create a view model specific to the view and use that.

Comment: How would I get the product id if the record does not exist yet I am using scaffolding for most of my code so excuse me if I being stupid

Comment: In that case, you first save the Product record and read the Id of that and use that to save.

Comment: Its not hitting my controller for some reason its just refreshing the page

Comment: I am usng      <form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="FileUpload" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">


          
                <input asp-for="Title" />
                <input asp-for="ProductId" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="Image" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
to get it to work but its not working its not hitting my controller

Comment: check the view source of the page and see whether your form's action attribute value is set to the correct action method (it should be the httppost action method)

Comment: See the edit i made to the answer. Specifically the form tag part in the view.

Comment: Yes it showing  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/Products/FileUpload">


 which is strange

Comment: Then it should submit to the action method. Do you have `[HttpPost]` on the `FileUpload` action method ? Do you have some javascript intercepting the submit button event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157199/discussion-between-david-and-shyju).

Comment: Thank you for detailed code.  It made it easy for me.  I was struggling since 2 days for it.